# How do you reverse a decimal number like 0.5

Tags: java

My question is how can you reverse a decimal in java?

Numbers such as 0.5 , 0.8 etc..

All my attempts at reproducing this code using a double variable instead of an int have literally caused my terminal to output " Infinity " or the symbol for infinity.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {                       
        int d = 0, 
               Result = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("enter a number: ");

        d = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); 

        while(d > 0)
        { 
            Result = (Result * 10) + d % 10; 
            d = d / 10;
        } 

        System.out.println("\nThe Reversed Number Is: " + Result);          

    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry guys I meant to put the output in.

So if you were to run this program the output would look like this (depending on the numbers you enter)

```
enter a number: 123456789

The Reversed Number Is: 987654321
```

My desired output would look like the following

```
Enter a decimal number: 0.5

The Reversed number is: 5.0 


import java.util.*; 
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {                       
        double d = 0, 
               Result = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("enter a number: ");

        //d = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine()); 
        //^ That will not cut off any result lol

        d = in.nextDouble(); 

        while(d > 0)
        { 
            Result = (Result * 10) + d % 10; 
            d = d / 10;
        } 

        System.out.println("\nThe Reversed Number Is: " + Result);          

    }
} 

enter a number: 0.5

The Reversed Number Is: Infinity
// The above result used d = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine()) 



 //The below output used d = in.nextDouble();
```

The only difference between those two methods of accepting input 
is that one accounts for people not following directions and the other doesn't
There is of course no try or catch etc.. or any thing here to terminate if any thing but a number is input and there does not need to be. The point is both of those input methods will generate the same results

```
enter a number: 5.0

The Reversed Number Is: Infinity
```

Comment: What is the desired output? Not sure I understand what you mean by reverse.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse"? What is the reverse of "0.5"?

Comment: Unrelated, but non-static variable names should be named with all lower-case to follow Java conventions.

Comment: Is the "reverse" of `0.123` `321.0`? Are you trying to reverse a number, or it's string representation? What should happen if you reverse `1.0000000000000000000001`?

Comment: If you are using Integer.parseInt, then you will loose all of the value after the decimal.

Comment: What is Result? You should change d from an int to a BigDecimal.

Comment: @Eric yes the reverse is the number printed in reverse so if it were 0.123 then yes the reverse would be 321.0

Comment: @matt this was simply an example to show you what I'm attempting to do, if you use type int with a decimal number you will always loose the value after the decimal point parsing the int is inconsequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use BigDecimal, because you are working with decimals. eg. 0.1 is a repeating number in base two. So it will get truncated.

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(in.nextLine());
```

With decimals, the value doesn't go to zero when you divide by 10 the same way an int does. Eg. 123 divided by ten becomes, 12.3. So your previous algorithm isn't going to work. Also you don't know how far to the right the number terminates. It can be done:

```
int n = 0;
while(d.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).intValue()>0){
    d = d.movePointRight(1);
    n++;
}
```

After that loop finishes you have a BigDecimal that is actually an integer. You can use your previous algorithm, but you need to place the decimal point back in the right place. Which is what n is for.

Comment: Yeah I knew that code wouldn't work because of the division that's why I was wondering I'll give BigDecimal a try thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Are you content with reversing the string representation?

```
String input = d.toString();
String reversed = new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString();

System.out.println("The Reverse of input is " + reversed);
```

Comment: EDIT: Sorry I misunderstood your comment, yes I'm perfectly happy doing it that way I was more so just curious if it was possible to do it with a double variable with out having to do a bunch of conversions.

Comment: @Afflicted it sounds like you are reversing the "string representation" of the number. User enters a string, you turn it into a number, you turn it back into a string, you reverse the string.

Comment: No? Integer.parseInt() converts to an integer if I wrote a function of type int and returned Result it would work due to it having been converted from a string to an int variable. I know how to do this using the method RC suggested but I was wondering if it was possible to due this using a double

Comment: @Afflicted: The question I think matt is trying to ask is why you want to have a number in the first place

Comment: The question was answered already. And I don't even understand how to begin to address your comment but i'll try " Why do you want to have a number in the first place" Well because I asked if it was possible to reverse a a decimal number, I laid out an example program using Integers, and explained that I wanted to reproduce that result with a double variable if it was possible. I already understood it could be done with strings which in the end is the easiest method. So again why do I want numbers? Because the question was about reversing numbers. Again it's been answered!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal(sc.nextLine());
    int integervalue =bd.intValue();
    //System.out.println(integervalue);
    BigDecimal floatpart=bd.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
    while(floatpart.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).floatValue()>0){
        floatpart = floatpart.movePointRight(1); 
    }
    int  floatValue=floatpart.intValue();
    int  intpart=0;
    while(floatValue>0) {
        intpart=intpart*10+floatValue%10;
        floatValue/=10;
    }
   int newfloatpart=0;
   boolean b=true;
   int count =0;
    while(integervalue>0) {
        if(b==true && integervalue%10==0) {
         newfloatpart=newfloatpart*10+integervalue%10;
         count++;
        }
        else {
            b=false;
            newfloatpart=newfloatpart*10+integervalue%10;
        }
        integervalue/=10;
    }
    System.out.print(intpart+".");
    while(count-->0) {
        System.out.print(0);
    }
    System.out.println(newfloatpart);
```